# Python argparse creates incorrect usage string when using nested sub-parsers

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I would like to build a (complicated) command-line argument parser using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module facilities.  The 'main' script can accept sub-commands, and some of the sub-commands also have their own sub-commands.  Here is a MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

def arg_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(required=True, dest="cmd")

    p = subparsers.add_parser("c1", help="Command 1")
    p.add_argument("foo", help="foo argument")
    p.add_argument("bar", help="bar argument")
    p.add_argument("-z", "--baz", help="baz argument")

    p = subparsers.add_parser("c2", help="Command 2")
    q = p.add_subparsers(required=True, dest="sub_command")

    r = q.add_parser("s1", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 1")
    r.add_argument("arg1", help="first argument")
    r.add_argument("-a", "--arg2", help="second argument")

    r = q.add_parser("s2", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 2")

    return parser


def main():
    args = arg_parser().parse_args()

    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So far everything works well, and the help messages generated by `argparse` look correct:

```
$ ./main.py
usage: main.py [-h] {c1,c2} ...

positional arguments:
  {c1,c2}
    c1        Command 1
    c2        Command 2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

$ ./main.py c2 -h
usage: main.py c2 [-h] {s1,s2} ...

positional arguments:
  {s1,s2}
    s1        Command 1 - Sub-command 1
    s2        Command 1 - Sub-command 2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
$ ./main.py c2 s1 -h
usage: main.py c2 s1 [-h] [-a ARG2] arg1

positional arguments:
  arg1                  first argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a ARG2, --arg2 ARG2  second argument
```

Now I would like to split the long `arg_parser` routine into sub-functions that create the parser as follows:

```
def sc1_parser():
    r = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

    r.add_argument("arg1", help="first argument")
    r.add_argument("-a", "--arg2", help="second argument")

    return r


def c1_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=None)

    parser.add_argument("foo", help="foo argument")
    parser.add_argument("bar", help="bar argument")
    parser.add_argument("-z", "--baz", help="baz argument")

    return parser


def c2_parser():

    r = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

    q = r.add_subparsers(required=True, dest="sub_command")

    q.add_parser("s1", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 1",
                 parents=[sc1_parser()])
    q.add_parser("s2", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 2")

    return r

def top_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(required=True, dest="cmd")

    subparsers.add_parser("c1", help="Command 1", parents=[c1_parser()])
    subparsers.add_parser("c2", help="Command 2", parents=[c2_parser()])

    return parser
```

(and obviously replace the call to 'arg_parser()' by 'top_parser()').

In this case, however, the help messages for sub-commands 's1' and 's2' are incorrect:

```
$ ./main.py -h
usage: main.py [-h] {c1,c2} ...

positional arguments:
  {c1,c2}
    c1        Command 1
    c2        Command 2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
$ ./main.py c2 -h
usage: main.py c2 [-h] {s1,s2} ...

positional arguments:
  {s1,s2}
    s1        Command 1 - Sub-command 1
    s2        Command 1 - Sub-command 2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
$ ./main.py c2 s1 -h
usage: main.py s1 [-h] [-a ARG2] arg1

positional arguments:
  arg1                  first argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a ARG2, --arg2 ARG2  second argument
$ ./main.py c2 s2 -h
usage: main.py s2 [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Any idea why this is happening?

My guess is that in the first version (`arg_parse()` routine) the sub-command parser (the parser for `s1` and `s2`) is added to the a parser returned from `add_parser` method of a sub-parser.  But In the second case they are added to a fresh 'ArgumentParser'.

Comment: `parser.add_subparsers` creates a `prog` string, which used by `_SubParsersAction.add_parser` to create the usage `prog` for each subparser.  I don't have time to going into more details.  After doing `sp = sp.add_parser(...)` look at `sp.prog` to see what it has done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add to your first script (before the return):

```
print("progs: ")
print("main: ", parser.prog)
print("   p: ", p.prog)
print("   r: ", r.prog)
```

a run is:

```
1319:~/mypy$ python3 stack63361458_0.py c2 s2 -h
progs: 
main:  stack63361458_0.py
   p:  stack63361458_0.py c2
   r:  stack63361458_0.py c2 s2
usage: stack63361458_0.py c2 s2 [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

`usage` includes the `prog`.  If you don't provide it, `argparse` derives it from `sys.argv[0]`, and for subparsers, adds on some strings to show the subparser's name (and required main arguments).  Code for that addition is in `add_subparses` and `add_parser`.

Adding similar prints to the `top_parser` case

```
1349:~/mypy$ python3 stack63361458_0.py c2 s2 -h
s2 prog:  stack63361458_0.py s2
top prog:  stack63361458_0.py
c2 prog:  stack63361458_0.py c2
usage: stack63361458_0.py s2 [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

`c2` gets the expected `prog`, but `s2.prog` is created without "knowledge" that it will be called by the `c2` subparser.  Using `parents` bypasses that link.

But I could supply my own `prog` for the sub-sub-parser:

```
s2 = q.add_parser("s2", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 2", prog=f'MyProg {sys.argv[0]} c2 s2 ')

1358:~/mypy$ python3 stack63361458_0.py c2 s2 -h
s2 prog:  MyProg stack63361458_0.py c2 s2 
top prog:  stack63361458_0.py
c2 prog:  stack63361458_0.py c2
usage: MyProg stack63361458_0.py c2 s2  [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

We can also supply a custom `usage`.

Instead of the `parents` mechanism which creates `s2` before `c2`, we could create `c2` and then pass that to the function that creates its arguments:

```
def c2_parser(q):
    r = q.add_parser("s1", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 1")
    r.add_argument("arg1", help="first argument")
    r.add_argument("-a", "--arg2", help="second argument")

    r = q.add_parser("s2", help="Command 1 - Sub-command 2")
```

and in `main`:

```
    p = subparsers.add_parser("c2", help="Command 2")
    c2_parser(p)
```

`parents` are (somewhat) useful as a means of adding the same arguments to multiple subparsers, but aren't necessary when just refactoring larger builds.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  So this means that, in order to get the correct usage string, the method `c2_parser()`  (that adds parsers for sub-commands `s1` and `s2`) needs to know that sub-commands `s1` and `s2` are reached via the command `c2`, and if, at some later time we decide to change the name of command `c2` (e.g. to `command2`) both `top_parser()` and `c2_parser()` methods need to be updated.  Am I right?  Does this suggest that my design pattern is poor?