# Argument not recognised at the terminal after creating subparser for it

Tags: python-3.x, shell, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to run a python script in the command-line and would like to parse multiple analyses command with different optional parameters e.g.:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='commands')

# Analysis A
analysis_a_parser = subparsers.add_parser('analysis_a', help='description)
analysis_a_parser.add_argument('-flag1', action='store_true', default=False,
                                help='flag1 description')
analysis_a_parser.add_argument('-flag2', action='store_true', default=False,
                                help='flag2 description')
analysis_a_parser.add_argument('-flag3', action='store_true', default=False,
                                help='flag3 description')

# Analysis B
analysis_b_parser = subparsers.add_parser('analysis-b', help='description')
analysis_b_parser.add_argument('--Flag1', action='store_true', default=False,
                                help='flag1 description')
analysis_b_parser.add_argument('-Flag2', action='store_true', default=False,
                                help='flag2 description')


args = parser.parse_args()
```

After running the program on the command-line

```
$ python script.py analysis-a -flag1 analysis-b -flag2
```

it throws an error saying unrecognized arguments: analysis_b

Please could you explain how I can pass multiple commands and optional parameters.

Comment: The `subparsers` mechanism only allows one command.  Once parsing has been passed to `analysis_a_parser` the main `parser` doesn't do any more parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for you reply. Is there a way to get around the single command constraint of subparsers mechanism?

Comment: Sure, do your own parsing of `sys.argv` :(

Comment: @hpaulj  Really?! I was hoping you would give me a nifty shortcut and help me avoid the labour of sys.argv parsing lol

Comment: i'm getting tired of hold `argparse` hands!  People have used nested subparsers.  `analysis_a_parser.add_subparsers` etc, but that gets messy pretty quick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361458/python-argparse-creates-incorrect-usage-string-when-using-nested-sub-parsers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042616/python-argparse-with-subparsers-and-optional-positional-arguments, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62250816/argparse-optional-arguments-with-multilevel-parser-subparser

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your help! Haha yeah these nested subparsers look like rabbit holes